# mutate() R replace -1 in column with the mean but all values are unconditionally replaced

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace

##### Problem

Just trying to impute or replace a `-1` value in column with the `mean()` value of data.frame column (`HRS1`). I had `str_replace()` and now `replace()` for `-1`, the column is numeric, but when test for `-1`, then **ALL values of the dataframe column are changed to `mean()` on `mutate`**.

This is NOT a missing value imputation/replacement, but a column that has `-1` values that need to be replaced.

##### Code

```
mean_HRS1 = mean(df_survey$HRS1)

df_survey %>% 
    mutate(HRS1 = replace(HRS1, -1, mean_HRS1))
```

Comment: Try: `df_survey = df_survey %>% 
    mutate(HRS1 = replace(HRS1, HRS1 == -1, mean_HRS1))`

Comment: `df_survey$HRS1[df_survey$HRS1 == -1] <- mean_HRS1`

Comment: Or `df_survey <- df_survey %>% mutate(HRS1 = ifelse(HRS1 == -1, mean_HRS1, HRS1))`

Comment: I'm not sure if the way you compute the mean is right. Should the `-1` be excluded when computing the mean? Given `HRS1` is `c(6, 7, 8, -1)`. The mean is `(6+7+8) / 3` or `(6+7+8-1) / 4` ??

Comment: Darren : good point, yes, -1 should be excluded, so one way is to subset and remove -1, then do a mean() and then bind the subset and and full set with the imputation of the mean on -1 values. thanks for that observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an logical vector, `HRS1 == -1`, or an index vector, `which(HRS1 == -1)`, into `replace`.

Another issue is that `-1` should be excluded when computing the mean. Given `HRS1` is `c(6, 7, 8, -1)`. `mean(HRS1)` is actually `(6+7+8-1) / 4`, but what you need should be `(6+7+8) / 3`.

```r
df_survey %>% 
  mutate(HRS1 = replace(HRS1, HRS1 == -1, mean(HRS1[HRS1 != -1])))
```